# What is the name of the network bridge adapter on Mac OS for VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I'm trying to configure VirtualBox on my Mac, and I'm not sure which one of these options I want.

[image]

en0 and bridge both give:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say "bridge0"?

Comment: Which adapter do you get your internet access from?  My guess is `en0`.

Comment: Ok, I tried both of those, they didn't work. I'm assuming one of them should?

Comment: So I assume you slightly mis-worded your question. It actually seems to be "What adapter should I select when bridging". What you provided doesn't suffice to solve the issue. Are you connected to WiFi? What's the VM's IP address and `resolve.conf`?

Comment: `inet address: 127.0.0.1` and resolve.conf added above.

Comment: That’s just `lo`, the loopback interface. You need to set up networking.